# MySQL --> MongoDB: Keep IDs or create mapping?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, migration, identifier

We are going to migrate our database from MySQL to MongoDB.
Some URLs pointing at our web application use database IDs (e.g. http://example.com/post/5)
At the moment I see two possibilities:

1) Keep existing MySQL IDs and use them as MongoDB IDs. IDs of new documents will get new MongoDB ObjectIDs.

2) Generate new MongoDB ObjectIDs for all documents and create a mapping with MySQLId --> MongoDBId for all external links with old IDs in it.

2 will mess up my PHP app a little, but I could imagine that #1 will cause problems with indexes or sharding?
What is the best practice here to avoid problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Keep existing MySQL IDs and use them as MongoDB IDs. IDs of new
>   documents will get new MongoDB ObjectIDs.

ObjectId very useful when you don't want/have a natural primary key for your documents, but mixing ObjecIDs and numerical IDs as primary keys can only cause you problems later on with queries. I would suggest a different route. Keep existing MySQL IDs and use them as MongoDB IDs; create new documents with numerical IDs, as you would do for MySQL. This way you don't have to mix data types in one field.

> 2) Generate new MongoDB ObjectIDs for all documents and create a
>   mapping with MySQLId --> MongoDBId for all external links with old IDs
>   in it.

This can work also, but you need, as you said, map your new and old IDs. This is probably some extra work which you can avoid if you leave your IDs unchanged.

> I could imagine that #1 will cause problems with indexes or sharding?

ObjectIDs and MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT IDs are both monotonically increasing so there wouldn't be much difference if they are used as a shard keys (you will probably use hashed shard keys in that case; you can read more details [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#can-you-shard-on-the-id-field)).

**Edit**

> Which problems could occur when mixing ObjectIDs and numeric IDs?

If you're doing simple equality checks (i.e get doc. with `{_id: 5}` or `{_id: ObjectId("53aeb2dcb9f8955d1a927b97")`) you will have no problems. However, range queries will be more complicated:

As an example:

```
db.coll.find({_id : { $gt : 5}})
```

This query will return you only documents with num. IDs.

This query:

```
db.coll.find({_id : { $gt : ObjectId("53aeb2dcb9f8955d1a927b97")}});
```

will return only documents that have ObjectIds.

Obviously, you can use $or to find either, but my point that your queries won't be as straightforward as with non-mixed Ids.

Comment: I don't know if I really like to use numeric IDs for my documents...in terms of sharding I really like the structure of ObjectIDs. Thus I tend to use the mapping strategy. Which problems could occur when mixing ObjectIDs and numeric IDs?

Comment: Good point. Mixing IDs seems to be a bad idea. I tried it, just to see if it could work: Frameworks might run into problems as well. (e.g. using Symfony with Doctrine ODM you have to convert passed IDs to ObjectIDs before using find() since the auto-converter will not work anymore) So creating a mapping-class might be the best solution for me. Thanks a lot @christian-p!